# Is there a way to control the width of the popover box created by the kableExtra package?

Tags: html, css, r, popover, kableextra

Just what the title says... I have some very long strings that I want to place in the popover box, but the resulting popovers are very long and narrow and therefore hard to read.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: You can do that by kable_styling, refer to its documentation: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/kableExtra/versions/1.1.0/topics/kable_styling